# How do i loop through the string and find out how many words are there?

Tags: c#

I need help with my problem:

Right now I have a WPF application with a form that includes a button and a textbox.

Also, I have an open file directory - that opens .cs and .txt files.

I need to loop through the string of those files and display the most common words in them, starting from the largest to the smallest.

For example, a string would be:

> "The sun is bright. The sun is yellow".

Would return:

> The = 2;
>
> sun = 2;
>
> is = 2;
>
> bright = 1;
>
> yellow = 1;

My code right as of now:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents |*.cs;*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false };
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            rtb.Text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);

        string[] userText = rtb.Text.ToLower().Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '=', '+', '}', '{', '\r', '\n', '(', ')', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (string word in userText) //search words in our array userText that we declared at the beginning.
        {

        }
   }
```

I am not sure how to continue from here... Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with @GTown-Coder 's approach as the easiest.  But if you really just want to know how to implement the same code using a dictionary as in your sample...

```cs
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents |*.cs;*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false };
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        rtb.Text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);

    string[] userText = rtb.Text.ToLower().Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '=', '+', '}', '{', '\r', '\n', '(', ')', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (string word in userText) //search words in our array userText that we declared at the beginning.
    {
      // Sample here
      if (frequencies.Contains(word))
      {
         frequencies[word]++;
      }
      else
      {
         frequencies.Add(word,1);
      }
    }

    foreach (var kvp in frequencies)
       Console.WriteLine("Word: {0} \t Frequency: {1}",kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: I would consider making you `Dictionary` case insensitive...  `var frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int> (StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`

Comment: Thank you for your solution! How exactly do i put the returned value into the textbox?

Comment: If you have some TextBox `txt`, then just set the `txt.Text` field. `txt.Text = string.Join("\r", frequencies.Select(kvp=>$"Word: {kvp.Key} Frequency: {kvp.Value}").ToArray())`.  Although you might be better off using a ListBox and assigning each line to a ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 2):

Using the example and expected output that you have provided for us, I was able to accomplish this by using `.GroupBy` along with creating an anonymous class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // example string
        var myString = "The sun is bright. The sun is yellow";

        // split the string into an array based on space characters and the period
        var stringArray = myString.Split(new char[] {' ', '.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // group the items in the array based on the value, then create an anonymous class with the properties `Word` and `Count`
        var groupedWords = stringArray.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Word = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList();

        // print the properties based on order of largest to smallest count to screen
        foreach(var item in groupedWords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Word + " = " + item.Count);
        }


        // Output
        ---------
        // The = 2
        // sun = 2
        // is = 2
        // bright = 1
        // yellow = 1
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This almost sounds like the original definition of a dictionary, so that might be a good place to start:

```
IDictionary<string, int> actualDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

You can place words in the dictionary, and increment their count each time you find them.

```
    IDictionary<string, int> actualDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (string word in userText) //search words in our array userText that we declared at the beginning.
    {
        if (!actualDictionary.ContainsKey(word)) {
            actualDictionary[word] = 0;
        }

        actualDictionary[word]++;
    }

    foreach(var thing in actualDictionary) {
        Console.WriteLine(thing.Key + " " + thing.Value);
    }
```

See a running example on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KscqDi).